# How to use keywords in SVN (TortoiseSVN)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I can't do a document with the Keyword Substitution tool to have only a few data as:
-Date
-Revision
-Author
-HeadURL
-Id

I'm doing a test but I can't implement the Keyword Substitution. I created a document Txt with the following information:

```
svn:keywords = Date Revision Author HeadURL Id

 $Id: $
 $Revision: $
 $Author: $
 $HeadURL: $
 $Date: $
```

I do not know whether it should be implemented in a txt file or in another format.

I am using TortoiseSVN and tools Subversion Edge.

Comment: Why would one do this?  that information is going to be stored in the repository.  why put the metadata in the file?

Comment: Subversion Edge gives me that info in the website but i needed a file with the Revision and author. Thats the reason why i ask for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use correct workflow and syntax

1. Add svn-property to file (as Ken noted)
2. Use proper syntax of enabled keywords inside text-file

`$Revision$`
`$Date$`
`$Author$`

Comment: Gives me the following error... when i Add svn-property to file...

**setting property 'svn:keywords' on non-local targets is  not supported**

Comment: @JorgeRocha - you must to do it with files in your local Working Copy, checkout'ed from repo

Comment: Thanks that was the info i needed.
TY

Answer (score 15):

You've done half of what you need. Now you need to use `svn propset` to do the rest of it, as it shows in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html), about halfway down the page:

You've done this part:

> For example, say you have a versioned file named weather.txt that looks like this:

```
Here is the latest report from the front lines.
$LastChangedDate$
$Rev$
Cumulus clouds are appearing more frequently as summer approaches.
```

Now you need to do the other half of it:

> With no svn:keywords property set on that file, Subversion will do nothing special. Now, let's enable substitution of the LastChangedDate keyword.

```
$ svn propset svn:keywords "Date Author" weather.txt
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'weather.txt'
$
```

The easiest way to set these properties using `TortoiseSVN` is to right-click the file, choose `TortoiseSVN->Properties` from the pop-up menu, and  then configure the properties there. You can find this info in the `Project Settings` page of the [`TortoiseSVN documentation`](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html#tsvn-dug-propertypage-editors); see `SVN keywords` roughly 2/3 of the way down the page. (There's no anchor provided, but you can search the page once you get there.)

Comment: And this secound part: 

"$ svn propset svn:keywords "Date Author" weather.txt
property 'svn:keywords' set on 'weather.txt'
$" 

is written in the same txt file (weather.txt)? or is written in the properties of TortoiseSVN?

Answer (score 12):

So for example if you want **Author**, **Date**, Rev**i**sion to be part of your SVN versioned file you have to add SVN Key propery to that file. So my initial file is called **example.xls** this is before the first commmit !!!

With content

```
<!--
$Rev::                      $:  Revision of last commit.
$Author::                   $:  Author of last commit.
$Date::                     $:  Date of last commit.
-->
<abv:container xmlns:abv="http://my_org/odel/common">
    <abv:object xmln
....
```

1. You have to set Keyword Substitution to your file, so for that purpose, if you are Tourtoise SVN user, right click on the file **example.xsl**

[image]

2. The Choose New Keywords
   [image]
3. Select Revision, Date, Author
   [image]
4. So now when you commit that file unless the Comment `<!--` SVN will add the needed values after the `::`. So After commit the file will look like:

   ```
   $Rev:: 938                  $:  Revision of last commit.
   $Author:: Xelian            $:  Author of last commit.
   $Date:: 2016-07-11 11:21:26#$:  Date of last commit.
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed steps. We don't all use command-line for CM.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered the same problem, but the syntax and the properties were correct.

In my case the problem was depending on the encoding of the file (it had UCS-2 LE BOM). I converted the file to ANSI and the keywords becomes replaced.