# Integrate SVN Info into Sourcecode

Tags: vb.net, svn

i'm using AnkSVN (TortoiseSVN based) in all my VB.NET projects. Right now I'm looking for a way to automatically write SVN Info (Date, Author, ...) directly to XML-Comments in my Sourcecode.

As English is not my native language and i'm only a programming beginner, I can't find the right terms for a successful google-search.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The term you're looking for is [keyword substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [(RESOLVE) How to use keywords in SVN (TortoiseSVN)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916283/resolve-how-to-use-keywords-in-svn-tortoisesvn)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, because that question already knows about SVN keywords but can't figure out how to use them. This question knows the desired outcome but does not know SVN keywords are the correct tool.

Comment: Marking as duplicate is fine with me. The other thread had some useful information that saved me some time... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Search for [svn keywords](https://www.google.com/search?q=svn+keywords&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and read [Keyword Substitution](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html) from SVN Book plus, maybe, H[ow to use keywords in SVN (TortoiseSVN)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16916283/resolve-how-to-use-keywords-in-svn-tortoisesvn) here